# Is it always necessary to have companyID and groupID in Liferay Service Builder?

Tags: liferay

I'm developing a liferay portlet. I use Service Builder. The question is that do I have to use companyID and groupID in my entity fields? What should I do if I don't want to have these fields? If I don't use them how can I use resourceLocalService.addResources() method?

Comment: are you using liferay 6.1? Because i (using 6.0.6) have not used either of the ID's you mentioned in many services i created.  

So for the service you should be able to create a method you like in you **LocalServiceImpl and implement what you want. When your done rebuild the service and deploy  

I dont know i something has changed in 6.1 to be honest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not required but they are convenient to have.

Liferay has many additional services available to you to use like permissions, users, document library. These services are almost always scoped to a portal instance, for example, Users are scoped to an instance which is tracked by `companyId`. Some are scoped to a group like document library.

So depending on what Liferay services you are planning to use and at what scope those services operate, it is convenient to have those values stored as well for easy lookup when you're calling those services you are using.

Comment: Reasonable depiction - even though I have always wondered why there is so much duplication of portal instance data per model!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the DBA team **didn’t specify these two foreign key fields in the tables,** but you add them anyway. You do this because the DBAs didn’t know the internal workings of Liferay when they designed the table.

These fields are internal to Liferay and are used for context purposes in non-instanceable portlets. 
CompanyId corresponds to the portal instance to which the user has navigated, and groupId corresponds to the community or organization to which the user has navigated.

Because you’ll use these field values as parameters in all your queries, the portlet will have different data in different portals, communities, and organizations.